# Angular + Jest + ChartJS - ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm trying to run a test on a component that uses [primeng charts](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart) that wraps the chart.js library.

I'm also using the [Jest presets for Angular](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular)

When I run my test, I get the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
```

It looks like the chart.js package is not recognized in the test,

Any solution for this?

Comment: You have to put Chart as part of the global configuration for Jest.

Comment: I did, but then it said that Chart is not a constructor. I'm not sure how to define Chart.